# React Regex string to html

Tags: javascript, html, regex, reactjs

I am currently working on a project and running into a little issue with parsing messages for links. I was wondering if there a better way to handle the conversion of a string of html to html then using dangerouslySetInnerHTML. As the method says it could be dangerous and I rather look for a cleaner way to handle it.

```
//Function for regex
var www_reg = /(?:^|[^"'])(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
message = message.replace(www_reg, '$1<a href="http://$2" class= "link" target="_blank">$2</a>');
return {__html: message}; 

//Render
<div className='message-class' onClick={this.clickedLink} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(display_message.last_message)}>
```

Comment: Can you give a sample for `message`? Also, I think implementing `encodeURIComponent()` would remove any danger

Comment: Will this always have an `<a>` ? If so, can you write that in the template, and change only the href attribute and the inner text? It looks like the things that are dynamic are strings, and not html.

Comment: The message can contain anything from plan simple text or a link. A common example would be someone sending a message such as "Hey checkout out this article www.cnn.com" or "Hey how is your day going". In the case of the first message only the www.cnn.com should get the link and in the second there would be no link. It would just pass in the message right to the div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something simple would be to split the string by the `regex` and turn the urls into JSX elements. Elegant solution that doesn't require `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      string: 'Hello www.example.com World www.stackoverflow.com',
      message: [],
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    let www_reg = /(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
    let blocks = this.state.string.split(www_reg);
    let message = blocks.map(block => {
      if (block.match(www_reg)) {
        return <a href={'//' + block}>{block}</a>;
      } else {
        return block;
      }
    });
    this.setState({ message });
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>{this.state.message}</div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('View'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='View'></div>
```

*PS: I had some trouble using your `regex` (it cut off some characters), so I modified it a bit. But it should work anyways, since I'm only using native JS functions here.*

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly. It is a much cleaner solution than injecting html into the div

Comment: Glad I could help. If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could parse the message string into an array of text and URLs (keeping order) and then map over that turning the URLs into actual React link elements. You could then plop that array straight into your div `<div>{arrayOfParts}</div>`

It looks like there is an npm module [react-linkify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-linkify) that will do that for you, or you can look at the source code [here](https://github.com/tasti/react-linkify/blob/master/src/Linkify.jsx) if you want to re-implement yourself.

Comment: thanks will give it a look over. Will probably have to go with a reimplementation cause the design calls for the ability to parse image links and display them in the chat